# Error: WebGL: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a JavaScript using the `THREE.js` package, I made some changes, saw the error, and undid all of the changes I have made.

However, the following error remained:

> Error: WebGL: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.

A google-search did not reveal something useful (16 hits!).

Anyone has any idea what is going on? Maybe this error has nothing to do with my script, but with the browser itself?

Comment: Try to break down your example to the simplest form where your error still shows up and post that code here. Otherwise it is kinda hard to guess what is happening.

Comment: This error cannot be reproduced. I just copied my entire javascript code WITHOUT ANY CHANGE to a different file, opened it in the browser (in a different tab) and the error vanished. Maybe the particular tab in the browser got crazy...? But anyway, it does not seem to have anything to do with javascript, but with the browser...

Comment: In my code the error happens after the page is reloaded 16 times, I think it has something to do with the destruction of the context.

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour like @bruce965 described. However, the question remains, how to cleanly destroy the old contexts?

Comment: I've placed a follow up questions for this @Afri as I am interested in finding a way to avoid this error. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54913836/2715716

Answer (score 20):

In my case, the solution was as simple as closing the browser window, opening a new one and reloading your project. The error appears only after I've reloaded my project in the same window more than 16 times.

Comment: yeah, reloading 15 times in FF rings up that error :D

Answer (score 14):

I'm seeing this error in FireFox (55) it's happened across a number of small test projects I've been working on.

The only solution I've found is to close and reopen FireFox, which leads me to believe that something isn't getting cleared out upon a page refresh. I've also noticed that leaving my browser open over night can result in very poor performance the following day until I reboot my PC. Perhaps either a Threejs issue or a FireFox (55) one when dealing with WebGL.

I'm going to continue investigating it as I work.

Comment: Can confirm, solved it for me with reopening Firefox

Comment: I get this problem too with two.js (three.js but 2D).

Comment: In Modern Versions of Firefox (linux), right clicking on the tray icon allows me to "Start New Instance".  This also fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fixed number of WebGL context instances available in Chromium, 16: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226868

It is possible you've either got 17+ tabs open simultaneously or you have one or context with a combined pixel resolution greater than 16 * 1024 * 1024.